# VS2017 + ReactJS + use of entity framework throws and error on migration

Tags: entity-framework, reactjs, react-redux, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I've started a new React+Redux project in VS2017 (.net core 2.0). Default template comes without database use, so I just added use of entity framework manually. It compiles well but when I try to add a migration using command

```
dotnet ef migrations add "Initial"
```

I'm getting the next error:

```
An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: One or more errors occurred. (Webpack dev middleware failed because of an error while loading 'aspnet-webpack'. Error was: Error: Cannot find module 'aspnet-webpack'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sibvic\AppData\Local\Temp\iu25u5dg.r0n:83:19)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\sibvic\AppData\Local\Temp\iu25u5dg.r0n:20:30)
at createWebpackDevServer (C:\Users\sibvic\AppData\Local\Temp\iu25u5dg.r0n:62:26)
at C:\Users\sibvic\AppData\Local\Temp\ftqvg4wq.l1l:114:19
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sibvic\AppData\Local\Temp\ftqvg4wq.l1l:133:38)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
Current directory is: C:\projects\test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0
)
Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time.
```

It looks like this features is too new. Not much information I can find. And can't figure out what's wrong by myself (at least yet, rubber duck method doesn't work either).

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue during migration from dotnet core 1.1 to 2.0.

I had to update implementation of my Program class to following:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

I know that this is not about React+Redux, but maybe it can help you.

Comment: This definitely helped me. Here is a link to the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/index#update-main-method-in-programcs